# post request python cross-domain to DWR server

Tags: python, python-requests, dwr

i want post request to dwr server with some payload date like this:

```
callCount=1
c0-scriptName=Manager
c0-id=3992_1389451476736
c0-param1=string:
c0-param15=string:
c0-param16=string:-1
c0-param17=string:1
xml=true
```

i use requests python my first questions is I do not know what kind of data accept dwr (string, json or ...) my code is

```
url = 'https://example.com/Manage.dwr'
headers = {
}

data = 'callCount=1c0-scriptName=MMTPManagerc0-methodName=saveMMTPOrderc0-id=7140_1389449863325c0-param0=string:072CD0A2FE4DAD0450457485587ADB5Cc0-param1=string:c0-param2=string:IRO1MAPN0001c0-param3=string:12190060428937%20%20c0-param4=string:Ac0-param5=string:20000c0-param6=string:0c0-param7=string:c0-param8=string:12913c0-param9=string:Lc0-param10=string:Jc0-param11=string:c0-param12=number:758944325c0-param13=string:2c0-param14=number:1389448044227c0-param15=string:c0-param16=string:-1c0-param17=string:1xml=true'



def req():
    r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    print r.text
    print r.headers
req()
```

and response is

```
//<script type='text/javascript'>
alert('Error. This may be due to an unsupported browser.\nSee the mailing lists at http://www.getahead.ltd.uk/dwr/ for more information.');
//</script>
```

for every idea and help Grateful
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having never heard of `dwr` before, I took a quick look and found the [Direct Web Remoting](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) website. Since it looks to require something that understands JavaScript on the client, you cannot use requests alone.

requests does not do any processing of the contents of the webpage. Since requests does not handle JavaScript for you, you'll need to use something more like selenium (which has bindings in python).

With something like selenium in the mix, you might need to change your `User-Agent` header in requests to something that looks like a real browser. Your request would look like:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers={'User-Agent': '<browser user agent>'}
```

Where `'<browser user agent>'` is a string taken from a browser. An example that might work can be

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
```

or

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: thanks for advise 
but when i enter address in firefox and try get request same error show me in alert box which issue cant for user-agent

Comment: @daviddavoodi then there's not much we can help you with. The link the alert gives you does not work for me so I cannot tell you which browsers are supported. Are you on a modern version of Firefox? Can you install a recent version of Chrome? If the answer to both is yes and you get the same alert, then I'm going to guess the website is broken, not anything else.

Comment: @daviddavoodi also, try visiting http://directwebremoting.org/dwr-demo/ to see if the bottom says "Test passed" for you. It works for me on Firefox 26 and Chrome 31.